# Use of 多い to modify the noun in this sentence

Tags: passive-voice, i-adjectives

そんなこんなで彼岸花には縁起でもなかったり『死』のイメージが強く、煙たがられることが圧倒的に多い花なのだ。

煙たがられることが圧倒的に多い花なのだ。

What exactly is the grammar of this sentence?  It cannot be "numerous flowers" but it has to be "numerous instances" but I don't understand why it's written like this?

"A flower with numerous instances of being disliked"?

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing the sentence wrongly. 煙たがられる..多い is a clause modifying 花. It is not really about *why*, but ことが多い is simply an idiomatic expression meaning *(subject) often...* Here 圧倒的に strengthens its 'often-ness'.

- [Difference between よく + verb, and verb + ことが多い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56075/45489)

Compare:

- その花は**煙たがられることが圧倒的に多い** The flower is quite often disliked.
- それは煙たがられることが圧倒的に多い花だ That is a flower which is quite often disliked.

In the latter, the bold part is put in the relative clause preceding 花 in the same way as

- その本は広く読まれている That book is widely read.
- それは広く読まれている本だ That is a book which is widely read.